# KeyCloak API services bottlenecked

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-services

I got this problem when using KeyCloak's APIs, the APIs usually do not return the result of the response and get the error code from the server side:
`ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Request failed with status code 401`. Observing my network, you can see that my client side often do not receive the expected response from server when calling "API to verify email". This happens regularly with other APIs and Verify Email API is just an example.
[image]

I think this comes from the missing configuration on the KeyCloak's Console. I have consulted many issues related to this issue but still can't find a specific solution, so please let me know if you see something is wrong in my settings.

Realm settings:
[image]

Clients service settings:
[image]

[image]

Service Account Roles:
[image]

Comment: A 401 error code means "Unauthorized". A typical cause may be an expired token. Can you take a look in the token, or try to increase the token life-time? Are there any error messages on the keycloak console?

Comment: I can make sure the token is not relevant about that. And can you tell me how to find the the error messages on the keycloak console? I just catch the error and log it on my terminal or take a look on browser's network

Comment: Can you show the details of the request producing the error?
And what calls uses /api/auth/verify/email? It must use some call to keycloak, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, I think that happen because my servers is not stable so when call through keycloak it sometimes get the message `ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Request failed with status code 401`, I have handled it successfully. Thanks for your advices.